# object openqa is not a member of package

Tags: scala, selenium

I try to run my `Scala` project from `Terminal` using this command:

```
/Users/dave/scala-2.11.7/bin/scala myPath.scala
```

And got this error:

> error: object openqa is not a member of package org import
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.{WebDriverWait, ExpectedConditions}

This project works fine via `Intellij`.

Answer (score 0):

use the `-classpath` parameter. e.g. `scala -classpath {path to your selenium jars here} myPath.scala`

For example for some of my project which I run from IntelliJ and where I use selenium the following works for me:
`d:\Projects\IMDBAverage\src\main\scala-2.11>scala -classpath "D:\Projects\IMDBAverage\target\scala-2.11\classes;D:\Enreach\MTV3\Automation\Automation\lib\selenium-java-2.38.0.jar;D:\Enreach\MTV3\Automation\Automation\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar" IMDBAverageCalculator.scala`

Notice here that I run scala from the sources directory, the same as you try to do in your example. In the classpath I add 2 selenium jars which are in completely other folder + also I add to the classpath other compiled classes from the project. Probably in your case it is not needed, but if except from the main class there are other classes in dependencies then you should do this.

Even better would be to run from the compiled classes folder, then the classpath gets shorter (notice `.` as a current directory there):
`d:\Projects\IMDBAverage\target\scala-2.11\classes>scala -classpath ".;D:\Enreach\MTV3\Automation\Automation\lib\selenium-java-2.38.0.jar;D:\Enreach\MTV3\Automation\Automation\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar" IMDBAverageCalculator`